# Getting the number of static attributes in a class

Tags: c++, sizeof, static-members, static-assert

I have a class consisting solely of static attributes acting as a sort of poor man's singleton. The purpose of which is to collect statistics from various points in the application. For our unit tests I created a shadow copy that can be used to get the difference between the one in production code.

Example:

```
struct Production {
    static ComplexClass value1;
    static ComplexClass value2;
};

struct ProductionShadow {
    static ComplexClass::ValueType value1;
    static ComplexClass::ValueType value2;
};
```

Since all members are static the shadow class cannot inherit from the production class and the attributes in the production class are complex objects with side effects and I only want the shadow to hold simple values for comparison.

In order to make the shadow class somewhat easier to maintain I wanted to add a static assert to check that whenever someone adds an attribute to the production class the shadow class is also updated.

Had the attributes not been static this could have easily been accomplished by doing the following:

```
enum { NumberOfProductionAttributes = sizeof(Production) / sizeof(ComplexClass),
       NumberOfShadowAttributes = sizeof(ProductionShadow) / sizeof(ComplexClass::ValueType) };
STATIC_ASSERT(NumberOfProductionAttributes == NumberOfShadowAttributes);
```

Apart from making the classes non-static, which I'd rather not do as I would have to turn the production class into a proper singleton, is there any way I can accomplish this check with the current implementation?

In runtime I have a method that verifies all the values in the shadow with the production class. Since the method has to be updated as well when a new attribute is added I would like to be able to count the number of attributes that have been verified and assert if the amount is different from the total number of attributes.

Example

```
bool ProductionShadow::verify() {
    std::size_t numberOfVerified = 0;
    #define VERIFY(x) do { \
        ++numberOfVerified; \
        // Verification code goes here \
    } while (0)
    VERIFY(value1);
    VERIFY(value2);
    ASSERT(numberOfVerified == NumberOfShadowAttributes);
    // Return result
}
```

If there is a GCC extension I can use that might be an acceptable solution even though I would prefer something portable.

Comment: Is there a reason not to have a single class with 2 global instances of it?

Comment: The types are different in the two classes as the production one holds a complex class with side effects that I do not want to duplicate in the shadow copy. The shadow is supposed to only hold values to be used in comparison.I'll update the problem description.

Comment: You could still create two separate classes with non-static members, and put static instances of them in the two classes. The size checks could then be performed against the original classes that have non-static members.

Comment: @DH OK - not sure I read the problem well enough!

Comment: @jogojapan An interesting solution, I would prefer not to make changes to production code (even one as simple as this) but if there is no better solution I think I will go with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case, here is the solution I suggested in the comments to the question. The idea is to create two classes that contain the data members in question *in the form of non-static members*:

```
struct ProductionStaticMembers
{
  ComplexClass value1;
  ComplexClass value2;
};

struct ProductionShadowStaticMembers
{
  ComplexClass::ValueType value1;
  ComplexClass::ValueType value2;
};
```

And then redefine the original classes to contain the classes defined above as *static members*. They would continue to function as before, and size checks could be performed against the types defined above.

```
struct Production {
  static ProductionStaticMembers static_members;
};

struct ProductionShadow {
  static ProductionShadowStaticMembers static_members;
};
```

Admittedly, this means a change in how the static members are accessed (because they are now members of another member); therefore many changes to existing code might be required.

Comment: An acceptable solution but I would really like to avoid the changes to production code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mix of `inheritance` and `template`.

```
enum ClassType { DEFAULT, SHADOW };

template<ClassType E>
struct Production_T
{
  static ComplexClass value1;
  static ComplexClass value2;
};
typedef Production_T<DEFAULT> Production;

struct ProductionShadow : Production_T<SHADOW> {
  // add only new 'static' members, others are copied from 'Production_T'
};
```

If some member is added to `Production_T`, the ProductionShadow will automatically updated. So you don't have to worry about duplicating the members in `ProductionShadow`.

Comment: An interesting solution but it will not allow me to verify that I have handled all attributes from the helper methods in the shadow.

Comment: @DavidHolm, I din't get your new question; why and what you want to verify ?

Comment: That the validation method in the shadow (used in unit tests) actually checks all the shadowed values against all the values in the production class. As these checks needs to be added manually in these methods it is easy to forget it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with macros.  Its a little bit ugly but would work:

productiondecl.h

```
struct PRODUCTION_TYPE
{
    PRODUCTION_VAR(ComplexClass, value1);
    PRODUCTION_VAR(ComplexClass, value2);
};
```

production.h

```
#define PRODUCTION_TYPE Production
#define PRODUCTION_VAR(type,name) static type name;
#include "productiondecl.h"
#undef PRODUCTION_TYPE 
#undef PRODUCTION_VAR
```

productionshadow.h

```
#define PRODUCTION_TYPE ProductionShadow
#define PRODUCTION_VAR(type,name) static type::ValueType name;
#include "productiondecl.h"
#undef PRODUCTION_TYPE 
#undef PRODUCTION_VAR
```

If you cant use type::ValueType in every case, write a metafunction to elucdiate the type:

```
template <typename T>
struct ShadowType
{
    // default type is type::ValueType
    typedef T::ValueType type;
};
template <> ShadowType<SomeOtherType>
{
    typedef SomeOtherTypeShadow type;
}
#define PRODUCTION_VAR(type, name) static ShadowType<type>::type name;
```

OR, you could avoid macros and use a template policy:

```
struct ComplexClass {
    typedef int ValueType;
};

template <typename T>
struct ShadowType
{
    typedef typename T::ValueType type;
};
template <typename T>
struct ProductionType
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <template <typename T> class Policy>
struct ProductionBase
{
    static typename Policy<ComplexClass>::type value1;
    static typename Policy<ComplexClass>::type value2;
};

struct Production : public ProductionBase<ProductionType>
{
};
struct ProductionShadow : public ProductionBase<ShadowType>
{
};
```

Or, a hideous hack, using macros to avoid changing the production code:

```
#define Production ProductionShadow
#define ComplexClass ComplexClass::ValueType
#include "production.h"
#undef Production 
#undef ComplexClass
```